# I can't answer anything on Apple.SE so there is no way to gain reputation now

Tags: support, questions

I just opened a account here on apple.stackexchange.com. I know the rules and was ready to answer some questions when I noticed that I am not allowed to answer any questions at all.

In the following picture I circled what I see: the link leads me to questions where all of them have this warning. Basically it's a loop. It leads me to questions that I can't answer because the community blocked low rep people. I can't find a single question that isn't blocked.

[image]

If someone could please confirm this and help me with this it would awesome.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/unanswered has a lot of questions which are not protected and therefore can be answered by any user. https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0%20hasnotice%3a0 should give you only unanswered questions which are not protected.

Comment: It mainly depends how you have your questions sorted. Sorting any questions list by votes will likely bring up protected questions because their popularity leads them to have many deleted answers from people who don't know the system. In terms of the /unanswered list or other lists of questions in general, sorting by newest will be the best place to start, both in terms of finding questions which aren't protected and also finding questions which you might be able to answer. —cc @patrix

Comment: @grgarside that makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can answer questions, except for a tiny percentage which are protected.

The question in your screenshot was protected automatically since there were many answers posted to that question which did not answer the question (spam, "me too", "thanks", etc) and have since been removed.

For more information about protected questions, see [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

If you want to provide an answer to a protected question, ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) for it to be unprotected. Otherwise, look for other questions which are not protected. You can find unprotected questions by searching for ‘[is:question hasnotice:no](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20hasnotice%3ano)’.

Comment: thanks, i was confused by this since a lot of the protected questions were about stuff that i actually know.